# Margin issue in HTML print

Tags: css, html

I am facing some issue regarding HTML multi pages printing.

Here is my code.

```
    @media print {
        body {
            margin-top: 50mm;
            margin-bottom: 50mm;
            margin-left: 0mm;
            margin-right: 0mm;
        }
   }
```

The above css works fine for the first page but it is not affecting for the rest of page.

Page 1:

[image: Margin are applied]

Page 2:

[image: Margin are not applied[2]]

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
@media print {
     body {margin-top: 50mm; margin-bottom: 50mm; 
           margin-left: 0mm; margin-right: 0mm}
}
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: same issue is coming.